# Cursor's iterate() method sometimes fails when converting a string to datetime

Tags: python, cursor, vertica, python-datetime, strptime

My goal is to fetch rows from **Vertica** that contain a column of type **Timestamp** with format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**, and do stuff with them.
My problem is that **cursor.iterate()** function sometimes throw an error, and I do not know why. 
It is very important to mention that I am using **vertica_python** library.

**Error Message:**

```
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError('_strptime',), <traceback object at 0x7f9f2fc29ef0>)`

**Traceback:** 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/..../sync.py", line 129, in fetch_exception_table
    for row in cur.iterate():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py", line 363, in iterate
    row = self.fetchone()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py", line 267, in fetchone
    row = self.row_formatter(self._message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py", line 446, in row_formatter
    return self.format_row_as_array(row_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py", line 462, in format_row_as_array
    for idx, value in enumerate(row_data.values)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/column.py", line 212, in convert
    return self.converter(s) if self.converter is not None else s
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/column.py", line 77, in timestamp_parse
    dt = _timestamp_parse(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica_python/vertica/column.py", line 94, in _timestamp_parse
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
AttributeError: _strptime`
```

**My code:**

```
        csv_buffer1 = cStringIO.StringIO()

        connection = Connection(config)
        cur = connection.get_cursor()

        cur.execute("select {} from DB.Table order by column;"
                    .format(HEADER_COLUMNS))

        for row in cur.iterate():
            csv_buffer1.write(tabulate(row, lsp=True))
```

**My Connection class:**

```
from vertica_python import connect

class Connection:
    cur = None

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.connObject = connect(**dict(config.items()))

    def get_cursor(self):
        self.cur = self.connObject.cursor()
        return self.cur
    #todo - return self.conn.... directly

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connObject.close()
```

In the code above, the execution fails on the **for** loop.

For some reason, the code does not always fail, it runs successfully sometimes and other times it does not.

Please see the figure below of the data in Vertica DB:

[Vertica Timestamp column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWb95.png)

Furthermore, it is pointless to use `cur.fetchall()` or `cur.fetchone()` instead of `cur.iterate()` for the sake of debugging because all of them use the same functions from **cursor.py** and **column.py**.

Comment: To see the error and debug you could use ```try: csv_buffer1.write(tabulate(row, lsp=True)) except: print("Fault occured on ", row)``` this will give us what went wrong during the loop. Then manually run ```tabulate(row, lsp=True)``` to what you can do about the issue.

Comment: @furkanayd I will do that and see if I can understand the root cause of the error.

Comment: probably you need some data cleaning (strip, split etc.) before running the tabulate method.

Comment: My tabulate method isn't the cause of the error. The program fails on **cur.iterate()**

Comment: Nope, your error code show that tabular __strptime method caused the fail. That means something in data cannot be converted to time format.

Comment: I do not see anywhere in my code where it says **tabulate**. Please elaborate.

Comment: Ok, now got it. Your iterator uses timestamps and your config connection has a problem inside itself. I don't think this issue caused by any part of your code. My recomendation use limits to test your data like try first ten rows then another and another. The data you use might have null/blank values which may cause this issue.

Comment: After I have looked into my code and my data for hours I assumed that the problem is not my code. But yet, I am not totally sure.
I am testing this on 5 rows, and all of them contain data and it is in correct format as I explained in my question. 
Additionally, it fails only part of the program executions and not all of them, which is a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused due to the use of multi-threading in my code.
The import of **_strptime** in some executions of the code sort of gets locked or gets used by another thread, so the second thread requesting it fails the import.

This has not happened to me in Python3 yet, so I assume it was fixed in Python3.

I can think of two possible workarounds:

1. In addition to importing **datetime**, also import **_strptime** even though it is not in use

   `import datetime
   import _strptime`
2. Use the function like so: `datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-12-11 08:58:01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`